# How do I get the "normal" theta with ebgaramond-maths in pdfLaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, ebgaramond

With `ebgaramond-maths` in pdfLaTeX, I'm getting a theta (with `$\theta$`) that's sort of a sparse, cursive, loopy thing. I want the normal theta.  Looking at `texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/ebgaramond/Specimen.pdf`, it appears that the theta I want is available, I'm just not getting it. I tried `\vartheta` with no luck.

I'm getting this: ϑ; I want this: θ.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\begin{document}
\[ \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried with other fonts ?

Comment: I have not had this problem with any other fonts.  Just tried libertine, CM, Baskervaldx, and XCharter without the issue.

Comment: I have pinged the maintainer of `ebgaramond-maths` to your question. You could as well write a mail to ReesC21 <at> cardiff <dot> ac <dot> uk as this is a bug in my honest opinion. You can find details on the font-mapping here https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond-maths but I am no expert on fonts so let's see what @cfr writes here.

Comment: This is somewhere in between a bug and a feature request. It's not entirely clear that a font shall support two variants of the same letter. It can, but it need not to.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi It is not a bug. The mathematics support is based on the italic, as the documentation explains. I can't find any evidence that the regular theta glyph is provided by the italic. The specimen linked in the question does not appear to include it. The package never claims to support ***upright*** Greek and doing so would require a significant amount of work, which I am not convinced is worth it for a package which inevitably provides at most partial support for mathematics.

Comment: @yo' ^^ There is no italic alternative in the specimen that I can see.

Comment: Sigh.  You're right, I was looking at an upright theta, which I wouldn't want for math.  Am I just out-of-luck, then?

Comment: @cfr Did you see dedded's last comment? (Perhaps you could write up an answer. Even "sorry, not available" is an answer.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. OK. Done. Not likely to be a very satisfactory answer but, as you say, it is an answer :(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that the absence of the regular theta is not a bug. It is, rather, a limitation of the font itself which simply does not include it.

The mathematics support is based on the italic, as the documentation explains. I can't find any evidence that the regular theta glyph is provided by the italic. The specimen linked in the question does not appear to include it:

[image: italic Greek]

The regular theta you see in the specimen is shown only in the upright shape:

[image: upright Greek]

**ebgaramond-maths** does not support upright Greek. Not only is italic Greek standard in maths, as I understand it. Supporting upright would require a significant amount of work, which would really not be worth it for a package which inevitably provides at most partial support for mathematics.

The only thing you could do is make a feature request to the developer of the *font*, asking that the regular theta be added to the italic. Given that the font is based on a historical one, I don't know whether the developer would be sympathetic to this request or not. (For example, I don't know whether the lack of the regular theta from italic reflects the standard at that time or not in the way that the lack of bold reflects the absence of bold type during that period.)